# CheckException only accepts 0-parameter methods; how do I test that other methods throw exceptions?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, exception, dunit

I'm wondering what's the best practice to test for exceptions in dunit. I am not very familiar with method pointers in Delphi. Is there any possibility to bind arguments to a method pointer so that it could be invoked without arguments. At the moment I always write an additional method which does this 'binding' manually. This is going to be annoying if the SUT has a lot of throwing methods.

```
// What i did before i knew abput CheckExcepion
procedure MyTest.MyMethod_BadInput_Throws;
var
    res: Boolean;
begin
    res := false;
    try
        sut.MyMethod('this is bad');
    except
        on e : MyExpectedException do:
            res := true;
    end;
    CheckTrue(res);
end;

// What i do now
procedure MyTest.MyMethodWithBadInput;
begin
    sut.MyMethod('this is bad');
end;

procedure MyTest.MyMethod_BadInput_Throws;
begin
    CheckException(MyMethodWithBadInput, MyExpectedException);
end;

// this would be nice
procedure MyTest.MyMethod_BadInput_Throws;
begin
    CheckException(
        BindArguments(sut.MyMethod, 'this is bad'),  // <-- how to do this
        MyExpectedException);
end;
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `StartExpectingException` to surround your your method call).

```
StartExpectingException(MyException);
MyMethod(MyParam);
StopExpectingException();
```

Comment: +1 this looks like the *right* way to do this; thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Or even better, just set the ExpectedException property inside your test.

Comment: Maybe add a try...finally here?

Comment: @Jeroen: No don't add a try...finally. It will in fact cause your test to fail incorrectly even when an exception is raised. `StopExpectingException` is implemented as: _I'm not supposed to be called; if I am, then an exception wasn't raised, so fail the test._ Putting it in a `finally` just forces it to fail the test. Strictly speaking, you don't need `StopExpectinException` at all. If the test method ends normally while in `ExpectedException` state, the test fails.

Comment: See that the MyMethod will raise an exception, and nothing after it will execute. If you have more than one check, they won't be executed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if DUnit supports it yet, but this is a perfect use case for anonymous methods which were introduced in Delphi 2010. If DUnit doesn't support it then you can easily modify the source yourself.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do i define a anonymous method? `CheckException` takes a `TTestMethod  = procedure of object`. My first try `CheckException(procedure begin raise Exception.Create('Error'); end, Exception);` Does not compile (incompatible types-> regular proc, method ptr)

Comment: @hansmaad You'd need to define the anonymous procedure as a variable in your test function. And you'd need to add a CheckException to TTestCase that had `reference to procedure` as its parameter rather than `procedure of object`. However, the answer of @TridenT to use StartExpectingException appears to be the right way to do this.

Comment: This is exactly what i did right know and it works. One have to overload the `CheckException` method taking a `TTestProc` instead of `TTestMethod`. Then you can use ananoymous methods. But StartExpectingException seems to be the way to go in dunit, even if i don't like it that i have to call the Stop.. method.

Comment: @hansmaad Be aware, that the code after `StopExpectingException` wont execute (at least in Delphi 2006).

Answer (score 3):

As noted, this is a great place for anonymous methods.

Here's how I do it.  I "borrowed" this from Alex Ciobanu:

```
procedure TestTMyClass.CheckException(aExceptionType: TClassOfException; aCode: TTestCode; const aMessage: String);
var
  WasException: Boolean;
begin
  WasException := False;
  try
    aCode;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if E is aExceptionType then
      begin
        WasException := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Check(WasException, aMessage);
end;
```

Then call it with something like:

```
CheckException(ETestingException, 
             procedure begin FMyClass.RaiseTestingException end,      
             'The ETestingException exception didn''t get raised.  That is impossible!');
```

Comment: I made a working version of this method and posted it below. Thanks a lot for posting this, it's very useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

To use `StartExpectingException()` is not the best way in case you want to test more then one Exception cases. In order to test all possible cases in my Test procedure, together with exceptions I use this algorithm:

```
uses
  Dialogs;
procedure MyTest.MyMethod_Test;
begin
  // Test for Exceptions
  try
    MyMethod(MyParam1CreatingException1);
    ShowMessage('Error! There should have been exception: Exxx here!');
    Check(false);
  except on E: Exception do Check(E is  ExceptionType1); end; // This exception is OK
  try
    MyMethod(MyParam2CreatingException2);
    ShowMessage('Error! There should have been exception: Exxx here!');
    Check(false);
  except on E: Exception do Check(E is  ExceptionType2); end; // This exception is OK
  // ... test other exceptions ...

  // Test other parameters
  CheckEquals('result1', MyMethod(MyParam1));
  CheckEquals('result2', MyMethod(MyParam2));
  // ... other tests ...
end;
```

The reason why I use `ShowMessage('Error! There should be exception: Exxx here!');`
 instead of the provided `Check(false, 'There should have been an EListError.');` method is that in my case (Delphi6) the `Check(boolean, 'Message')` does not work - it does not show the message in case that Check is inside `try...except` block (do not know why).

Answer (score 0):

This is the working and improved version of Nick Hodges' answer, which sub-classes DUnit's `TestFramework.TTestCase`:

```
uses
  TestFramework, System.SysUtils;
type
  TTestCode = reference to procedure;

  TTestCasePlus = class(TestFramework.TTestCase)
    procedure CheckException(
      ExceptionType: TClass; Code: TTestCode; const Message: String = '');
  end;

implementation

procedure TTestCasePlus.CheckException(
  ExceptionType: TClass; Code: TTestCode; const Message: String = '');
{ Check whether some code raises a specific exception type.

Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5615560/797744

Example:

  Self.CheckException(EConvertError,
                      procedure begin UnformatTimestamp('invalidstr') end);

@param ExceptionType: The exception class which we check if it was raised.
@param Code: Code in the form of an anonymous method that should raise the
  exception.
@param Message: Output message on check failure. }
var
  WasRaised: Boolean;
begin
  WasRaised := False;
  try
    Code;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      if E is ExceptionType then
        WasRaised := True;
  end;
  Check(WasRaised, Message);
end;
```

A nice bonus to this method of checking if an exception was raised over `Start/StopExpectingException()` is that you can run the testrunner in the debug build and it won't keep bothering you with "Exception was raised. Break? Continue?" every time an exception is raised--even though it was handled.